# How to hide featured image in Wordpress Single Post pages?

Tags: image, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

there are some posts about this but solutions are not working for me..

I ll be appreciated for your help..

hier is the code @ my single.php

`<?php echo '<div class="thecontent">' . apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content()) . '</div>';`

I ve tried this one but I dont know how can I replace the code?

```
echo preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '', get_the_content(), 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can hide your featured image for particular post using css also

like,

```
#(here your id of your post)img {
display : none;
}
```

OR

```
  #(here your id of your post)img {
    visibility : hidden;
    }
```